# How to have JLabel to be docked on the left side always in GridBagLayout as the JDialog size changes?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

When the JDialog window has it size changed the JLabel and JTextField do not stay left aligned. Is it possible to have JLabel to be docked to the left side of the JDialog always as the JDialog size changes and have the JTextFields to increase in width to cover the rest of the horizontal space to right side. I thought a grid bag layout would help in this approach but so far I have only been able to tell it to what coordinates to put each component in the grid b
ad. Is there any advice or tips on what to do?

My code is below, which I did base or make a dummy example from another example I saw online.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class GridBagLayoutExample extends JDialog {
    GridBagLayoutExample() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        
        final JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
        
        
        JLabel firstNameLabel = new JLabel(); 
        firstNameLabel.setText("1st Name");   
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0; 
        controls.add(firstNameLabel,c);  
        
        
        
          
         JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField("Please input a 1st Name"); 
         c.gridx = 1; 
         c.gridy = 0; 
         controls.add(firstNameField, c); 
          
         
         
        JLabel secondNameField = new JLabel(); 
        secondNameField.setText("2nd Name");  
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1; 
        c.gridwidth = 1; 
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        controls.add(secondNameField, c);
        
        JTextField secondNameLabel = new JTextField("Please input a 2nd  Name"); 
        c.gridx = 1; 
        c.gridy = 1; 
        controls.add(secondNameLabel, c); 
         
        JLabel thirdNameLabel =  new JLabel();
        thirdNameLabel.setText("3rd Name");  
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2; 
        controls.add(thirdNameLabel, c);
        
        
        JTextField thirdNameField = new JTextField("Please input a 3rd Name"); 
        c.gridx = 1; 
        c.gridy = 2; 
        controls.add(thirdNameField, c); 
        

        
      
        controls.add(new JPanel(){
            {     
             }}); 
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            pack();
        

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). You can use the `weightx` constraint to allow your text fields to grow.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`GridBagConstrains#weightx`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutExample extends JDialog {

    GridBagLayoutExample() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        final JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);

        JLabel firstNameLabel = new JLabel();
        firstNameLabel.setText("1st Name");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        controls.add(firstNameLabel, c);

        JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField("Please input a 1st Name");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        controls.add(firstNameField, c);

        JLabel secondNameField = new JLabel();
        secondNameField.setText("2nd Name");
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        controls.add(secondNameField, c);

        JTextField secondNameLabel = new JTextField("Please input a 2nd  Name");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        controls.add(secondNameLabel, c);

        JLabel thirdNameLabel = new JLabel();
        thirdNameLabel.setText("3rd Name");
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        controls.add(thirdNameLabel, c);

        JTextField thirdNameField = new JTextField("Please input a 3rd Name");
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        controls.add(thirdNameField, c);

        controls.add(new JPanel() {
            {
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

`GridBagLayout` is very powerful, but that makes it also very complex ;)

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong or misunderstood but do not see it docking the jlabels to the left side and allowing the jtextfields to resize as the window size changes on my end. I ran your code example but that did not work. I ran it on a Windows Device. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Can't say - the example works just fine for me